# Duplex of BSD sockets

Tags: winsock, bsd, sockets

As the title states, what are the duplex of the BSD sockets, full? - and that is on the same single socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the `socket(2)` manual page, you will see that `SOCK_STREAM` type sockets are full-duplex. Same for Windows, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx .

Comment: Do you know about the thread safety-ness of full-duplex. Can I recv on one thread (say, a receiving thread, on a loop), while simultanously send messages from a different thread?